# Deployment Strategy for CodeIgniter PHP + GitHub + Site5 (or any webhost)

Tags: php, deployment, codeigniter, continuous-integration, github

Hello
I am not super experienced with PHP and large projects using it, most of my tinkering around has been in Rails with EngineYard (life seemed simpler back then). But in PHP, I haven't found anything that comes really well integrated with GitHub right out of the box. So I am looking for an easy solution to deployment for now and hopefully setting the stage for continuous integration in the future when I get around to writing the tests and such.

Here's what I have so far:

- GitHub repo with my codebase
- Alpha version of the app in CodeIgniter in PHP
- Run of the mill webhost account with Site5 for staging/development

Currently, I deploy by uploading the latest batch of code via FTP onto my site.

For one, I would like to get to a one-step deployment process. Just a simple git push would do the trick. Is Phing overkill for now?

What are the steps you might recommend as best practices?

Thank you.

Comment: Top options so far:
1. Deploy script
2. ANT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend creating deploy script(s), especially at the beginning. It's a lot easier to start working on them since there are not that many things to do. Not to mention running a single deploy command is easier than doing all the steps manually. Even for small projects. Projects tend to complicate the deployment with time.

If it helps, we are currently using ANT (well, switching), we have dropped Phing due to not being developed/maintained anymore.

Comment: This is what I thought would be best for us for now. Write a simple deploy script to push out from the dev machine to github to the staging server & update the db if required. Would you still recommend getting into ANT at this stage or stick to the script?

Comment: It depends on what are you used to do. Our deployment strategy (and development for that matter) is the same at the beginning; project structure, dependencies etc are the same for any new project. Hence each new project has the same basic deploy script. In our case, we start with a simple Ant script and add what is needed when needed for the project in question.

Comment: Makes sense David. Standardizing/template_driven development gets the ball rolling really quickly. Thank you.

Comment: Is Phing really not being developed any more? I see new releases as recently as July 2011...

Comment: @medicdave It seems Phing is alive again, thanks for pointing it out. Nevertheless, we are sticking with Ant :)

Answer (score 0):

I use [Beanstalk](http://beanstalkapp.com/features), and they have great deployment methods available. Once you commit, you can set up auto deployment settings, with a simple click.

Comment: Thank you. I gotta check it out soon.